# SharePoint Best practice for multiple images per list item

Tags: lookup-column

I have to create a simple Classifieds system in SharePoint. One classified item can have multiple images. Does anyone have suggestions on design for this initiative? For example, should I have a custom list (Classifieds) which will contain a lookup column to an Assets library (ClassifiedPhotos)? Or can a single library item hold multiple images without using a lookup column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 approaches:

1. Lookup Column to the Images library of your preference (the one you suggested)
2. Attachments in the List Item
3. **Document Set.** Basically a Document Set is a type of Item that can have custom fields. It's very particular in that it can hold multiple files, and provides a welcome page that is very useful to quickly see which files are associated with the Document Set. **This would be my preference. It has the best of both worlds.**

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-document-sets-HA101782466.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff603637(v=office.15).aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/create-and-configure-a-new-document-set-content-type-HA101782461.aspx

Comment: I went with the lookup after. Although I did explore Document sets and they seem useful, are not ideal for my requirements. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom List, 'Classifieds', then an Assets Library, 'Classified Photos'.

In the Assets Library, 'Classified Photos', add a lookup column to point to the Classifieds List.

That way, when you upload an image, you just choose the corresponding *Classified*

That's the proper way to represent the one-to-many relationship, not by adding the lookup column to the 'Classifieds' List.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, thanks for that correction